# Meaning of the word "indigenous"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I am reading some text and don't understand this:

> Unfortunately, we can't live off the fat of the land although
>   **indigenous** people did so for thousands of years.

What **indigenous** means and how would we explain the point of all sentence?
I suppose the first part is an idiom because of the weird choice of words, but I am stuck. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Have you looked up "indigenous" in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writing is clumsy. The writer appears to be saying that we cannot all "live off the land" (get our individual subsistence by farming), as people did in pre-industrial times. However, he or she has chosen the wrong idiom. To "live off **the fat of** the land" means "to be rich enough to live well without having to do very much". Furthermore, "indigenous" or "first nation" people are those who originally lived in places which were later colonised, and while they often practised subsistence farming, so did people in e.g. Europe before the modern period.

[Live off the land](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/live-off-the-fat-of-the-land)
[Live off the fat of the land](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/live-off-the-fat-of-the-land)
[Indigenous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/indigenous)

Comment: Either the author has chosen the wrong idiom, or else he or she has the backwards notion that indigenous peoples were indolent (and that explained their supposedly stunted development). This would be more likely if the author were writing about Hawai'ians rather than Haidas, or Tahitians rather than Tlingits. For the sake of the author, let's hope you're right.

Comment: He or she probably wanted to write "primitive" or something like that, but decided not to, and sought out what he or she thought was a modern acceptable equivalent.

Comment: I also thought that it should be used _live off the land_ that describes surviving based on what nature provides, but this_fat_here has completely confused me. Thank you for your help, at least I have learnt a new idiom :)

Answer (score -2):

> **Indigenous peoples**, also known as first peoples, aboriginal peoples or
>   native peoples, are ethnic groups who are the original settlers of a
>   given region, in contrast to groups that have settled, occupied or
>   colonized the area more recently. 
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigenous_peoples

---

> **live off the fat of the land** ​ to be rich enough to live well without
>   having to do very much
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/live-off-the-fat-of-the-land